# pass parameter to angular directive on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to get parameter on click using directive.I want to get child data in the click event for checking has child or not.

.....

html

```
div ng-app="treeApp">
<ul>
    <treeparent></treeparent>

</ul>
```

js

```
(function () {
var treeApp = angular.module('treeApp', []);
treeApp.directive('treeparent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<button addchild child='m'>ajith</button><div id='new'></div>"
    }
});
treeApp.directive('addchild', function ($compile) {

    return {
        scope: {
            'child':'='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            debugger;
            element.bind("click", function (scope,attrs) {
                debugger;

//here i want to get hild ie 'm'
 angular.element(document.getElementById('new')).append("<div><button button class='btn btn-default'>new one</button></div>");


                 });
        }
    }

});
})();
```

plz help me

Comment: What is the problem? `scope.child` doesn't work?

Comment: yes scode.child was undefined

Comment: It will be `scope.child`. Also **remove** this `angular.element(document.getElementById('new')).append("<div><button button class='btn btn-default'>new one</button></div>");` - untill you went too far in totally wrong direction.

Comment: dfsq i want to append that div on click. thats y . can you suggest another way?

Answer (score 1):

So, i think `scope.child` is `undefined` becouse it is overlaps in declaring event.

You can define variable before event binding

```
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var child = scope.child;
        element.bind("click", function (scope,attrs) {

           // here you can use child
           console.log('child', child);

        });
    }
```

or declare different argument names

```
    link: function ($scope, $element, attrs) {
        element.bind("click", function (scope,attrs) {

            // here you can use $scope.child
            console.log('$scope.child', $scope.child);

        });
    }
```

---

Is a callback has `scope` and `attrs` argument? May be it has only one `$event` argument?

```
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        element.bind("click", function ($event) {

            // here you can use child
            console.log('child', scope.child);

        });
    }
```

Comment: Anton , sorry its not

Comment: callback for `bind` has only one `$event` argument

Comment: is any way to call directive function from controller

Comment: Directive-controller or parent scope controller?

Comment: Yes, you can do it
**i created new answer, becouse comment can be only inline**

Answer (score 0):

Example for call method from directive in parent scope

parent template

```
<test-dir data-method="myFunc"></test-dir>
<button ng-click="myFunc('world')">click me</button>
```

or

```
<button test-dir data-method="myFunc" ng-click="myFunc('world')">click me</button>
```

directive

```
.directive('testDir', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            method: '=',
        },
        controller : function($scope) {

            $scope.method = function(text) {
                alert('hello '+text);
            };

        },
    };
})
```